# insert PCDATA from the child element into an attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to insert PCDATA from the child element into a selected node attribute

XML

```
<root>
  <tag>
     <tag1>SOME TEXT</tag1>
  </tag>
</root>
```

MY XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <tag-out>
            <xsl:attribute name="text">
                <!-- What should I select? -->
                <xsl:value-of select="tag/tag1/???"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        <tag-out>
    </xsl:template>

    ...........

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output XML

```
<root-out text="SOME TEXT">
   <tag-out/>
</root-out>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with simply doing

```
   <tag-out text="{tag/tag1}"></tag-out>
```

? Of course your sample with

```
    <tag-out>
        <xsl:attribute name="text">

            <xsl:value-of select="tag/tag1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    <tag-out>
```

is also possible. But as your post is tagged XSLT 2.0 I would at least do

```
    <tag-out>
        <xsl:attribute name="text" select="tag/tag1"/>
    <tag-out>
```

if you really need `xsl:attribute`.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, I wrote a working example with <xsl:value-of select="tag/tag1"/> :) and have error in my main script. Problem solved